# spamassassin/auto-whitelist, can I delete it?

Tags: spamassassin, quota

I found a huge file, .spamassassin/auto-whitelist, in my user directory, with my permissions, taking up a large percentage of my quota.  Can I safely delete it, or otherwise shrink it down?

Answer (score 0):

It is [Auto-WhiteList](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AutoWhitelist) database of Spamassassin. It contains the history of spam scores of all messages sent from each email+IP pairs. It is used by Spamassassin to descrease spam score for messages sent from email+IP with good history of sending ham emails and to auto blacklist messages sent from email+IP which sent a lot of spam in the past.

You can delete it (but you'll lose all spam score history) or you can shrink it by removing all one-off email addresses with [this](http://www.deepnet.cx/~kdeugau/spamtools/trim_whitelist) Perl script.